# React Native undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response Json.results[0].formatted_address')

Tags: react-native, expo

While running React apps in android mobile

### Console

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 
'responseJson.results[0].formatted_address')
 * src\screens\MapScreen.js:194:55 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

While running React apps in android mobile

### check this

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 
'responseJson.results[0].formatted_address')
 * src\screens\MapScreen.js:194:55 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals




_getLocationAsync = async () => {

let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
if (status !== 'granted') {
  this.setState({
    errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
  });
}
let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})
    if(location){
        var pos = {
            latitude:  location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          };
          var curuser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

         if(pos){
          let latlng = pos.latitude + ','+pos.longitude;
          return fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latlng+'&key=AIzaSyDZ7HSZZafEkBmuwD2CdHrLJNn3kEm39Fo')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
          if(this.passData.wherelatitude == 0){
            this.setState({
                whereText: responseJson.results[0].formatted_address,
                region: {
                    latitude: pos.latitude,
                    longitude: pos.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }
            },()=>{
                this.forceUpdate();
                this.showDriver();
                this.passData.wherelatitude = pos.latitude
                this.passData.wherelongitude = pos.longitude
                this.passData.whereText = responseJson.results[0].formatted_address;
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + curuser+'/location').update({ 
                    add:responseJson.results[0].formatted_address,
                    lat:pos.latitude,
                    lng:pos.longitude
                }) 
            });

            }else{
                this.forceUpdate();
                this.showDriver();
                this.passData.wherelatitude = pos.latitude
                this.passData.wherelongitude = pos.longitude
                this.passData.whereText = responseJson.results[0].formatted_address;
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + curuser+'/location').update({ 
                    add:responseJson.results[0].formatted_address,
                    lat:pos.latitude,
                    lng:pos.longitude
                }) 
            }

          })
          .catch((error) =>{
            console.error(error);
          });
        }
      }
```

}

Comment: please check if index 0 is set before using it

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: I think u are getting empty results array, try to handle those as well.

Comment: Can you please add some related code ?

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'responseJson.results[0].formatted_addres
s')
* src\screens\MapScreen.js:194:55 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: Could you please add the console log out put of the response

Comment: added please check